# expected type-specifier C++ template class

Tags: c++11

So I am trying to implement a Vector class.

I am getting the error *"expected type-specifier before '[' token"* in my 'at' function, as shown below:

```
T Vector<T>::at(unsigned i){
    return operator[i]; 
}
```

I have tried:

```
return this->operator[i];
```

and

```
(*this).operator[i];
```

but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: `operator[]` is a *function* that you should call as a function. Or use the overload as e.g. `(*this)[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax would be

```
return this->operator[](i);
```

or more canonically

```
return (*this)[i];
```

Comment: You don't need `this->` in the first case (but I agree it actually makes the code more readable).